# Any way around circular reference dependancy in C#?

Tags: c#, circular-reference

I have a solution with 3 projects

```
Project1 - main application
Project2 - graphing application
Project3 - graphing library
```

The data is accessed from objects in Project1.  Project 1 has a reference to project 2 to create a display of the data (form), and projectg 2 has a reference to project 3 to do the actual heavy lifting of rendering the graphs.

Now, project 3 needs to have access to the objects/methods of project 1 as that is where the data lives.  But when I add a reference from project 3 to project 1, I get an error about circular references.

How can I solve this issue?

Thank,
Reza

Comment: maybe you should restructure your architecture

Comment: @luis_laurent if I had know about this restriction, I wouldn't have architected it this way.  I'm still learning C#.  I'm wondering if just merging projects might be easiest..

Comment: ok too bad, I do not really know if there is a manner to solve this problem, but the only way I see is to  refactor your projects.

Comment: I'm moving the data portion into a new project to see if that fixes it, as per the solutions below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to keep the flow in one direction.. down.

To get around that, I generally have a "Models" project. Data models are stored in this project all by themselves and this project is referenced by any other project that requires them.

Answer (score 4):

No; there is no way around this. You have a circular dependency. You will need to refactor the layers of your application.

What I find works best for me in terms of layers (from lowest to highest)

1. Global methods & configuration (i.e. things like base type extension methods, system messages, etc).
2. Data access layer. No business logic; only data CRUD logic.
3. Business layer. Add business logic here.
4. UI value add layer. This is where things like your graphing libraries would go. (optional)
5. UI layer. This is where you build the UI that the end user sees.

Answer (score 2):

One way to deal with circular references is to restructure your application.

Create project 4, and put the interfaces common to the projects in there. You can include project 4 from all other projects. Now implement interfaces from that project in one of the three other projects, and use implementations through a factory mechanism of some sort (an inversion of control container is good too, but it may be an overkill for simpler applications).